# Putty clone that does not store settings in Registry

Tags: windows, gratis, ssh

I have a hard time [migrating the Putty settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023920/how-to-export-import-putty-sessions-list) from the Registry to my new machine.

Therefore I'm looking for a Putty clone that

- either stores the settings in a file format, so that it's possible to copy the files
- or has capabilities to export and import the settings (just like WinSCP or HeidiSQL)

Other than that I'm quite happy with Putty as it is. I do not need nor want many other features. Basically:

- save "sessions" or "connections" or whatever you call it
- key file based authentication mandatory
- Windows 10 support
- gratis

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: well, it's not so hard, but easy to forget. Usually I just want to copy all the data over from the old PC to the new PC, but obviously I will not copy the whole Registry.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the registry settings is not difficult. You do not have to use command-line tools. Check the [answer by @Sireesh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13023920/850848#32930474) to learn how to use `regedit` GUI tool.

And even if you have forgotten to export Windows registry before scrapping your old machine, you can still export the settings from a file system backup. See [How to copy PuTTY sessions from crashed computer?](https://superuser.com/q/1155050/213663)

---

Anyway, the KiTTY is a PuTTY clone that supports using an INI file instead of registry:
https://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/Portability.md#Portability

---

It seems that you use WinSCP, so note that you can use [WinSCP as a site manager for PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_winscp_as_putty_session_manager) (even if you use an INI file with WinSCP). That way you do not have to keep two sets of sessions.

Comment: Indeed, in some cases I use WinSCP+Putty, but only if the workflow involves copying files first, then SSHing to the machine. For other work, I used Putty directly. kitty seems to be a good replacement for Putty :-)